# Perl pack and unpack binary data in a variable

Tags: perl

I have some binary data that comes to me from a library function which I store in a variable called:  $data

If I hexify this binary data with:
$hexstring = unpack "H*", $data;

It performs this hex transformation correctly, I verified my results against the unix commands:  od -c  and  xxd -p  :-)

My question is how to I do the reverse operation to pack this data back into a  $newdata variable from the hex data ?

if I do a ref($data), it returns a blank result, so I don't understand what format this binary data is originally formated in the $data variable.  The library author tells me it is a string, but my experience trying to pack a string, it does not produce the correct result.

I have tried various attempts to  "pack"  but I don't seem to know how to pack this correctly.  I am stumbling on something.  :-)

Please help me to understand my packing errors ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your hex string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's pretty straightforward in this case. The inverse operation of `unpack 'H*'` is `pack 'H*'`

Here's a program demonstrating

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use 5.10.1;

my $data = "\x01\x23\x45\x67\x89\xAB\xCD\xEF";

my $hex = unpack "H*", $data;
say $hex;

my $newdata = pack "H*", $hex;
say $newdata eq $data ? 'OK' : 'FAIL';
```

#### output

```
0123456789abcdef
OK
```